# Setting up Catalan on Google TTS engine

Tags: languages, google-speech-services

I'm using Xiaomi Redmi Note 12 Pro (MIUI Global 14.0.6). I'm not able to set up the Catalan language in the Google TTS engine. Basically, it does not accept any language which is not linked to a country (like Croatian or Serbian for example).

My phone system language is set to Catalan. Any other language linked to a country works. By languages not linked to a country, I mean those appearing on the list of languages which do not have the country next to the language e.g. English (United Kingdom). For Catalan, it appears as is in the list with no country next to the name. I guess if it would be listed as Catalan (Spain), it would work. Any support would be highly appreciated.

I can't use another TTS engine as I'm using a Samsung 5 Pro smartwatch and the Samsung Galaxy watch manager app only supports 2 TTS engines: native Samsung TTS and Google. Unfortunately, Catalan is not supported by Samsung TTS (at least I was not able to find it). Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looking at [the language list of Google TTS (Speech Services by Google)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Services), looks like it doesn't support Catalan and a few other languages. I'm not sure the user can do anything about it since it depends on Google's development.

Comment: Catalan is supported, https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices

Comment: The link you provided belongs to Wikipedia!

Comment: I deliberately linked to Wikipedia because the language support for the Google Cloud TTS API (for developers) is different from the Speech Services Android app (for end-users), while both were developed by Google and thus depend on Google's own internal development/policy/etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.

Comment: The weird thing is that 2 weeks ago I managed to set up catalan and now it is no longer possible but I do not know the reason for that. Maybe some app was updated, still looking for a solution. Thx